# Multiple result types in Struts2?

Tags: java, json, jakarta-ee, struts2, tiles2

I have a Struts2 application where I using Tiles. How can I get multiple result types in action-mappings? because I need to set de output as JSON data, and Tiles simultaneous. I have tried:

```
<action
    name="home"
    class="com.deveto.struts.actions.HomeAction" >
    <result name="success" type="tiles,json">tiles.home</result>
</action>
```

But this isn't working

Comment: You cannot have multiple types for a response; you can only commit a single response to an HTTP request. Perhaps you can explain in more detail what you are trying to do.

Comment: As steven said you can not have both. It doesn't make sense. `tiles` result type gives you the HTML whereas `json` type gives you the ... well ... JSON ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To my knowledge there is no way to return multiple things simultaneously. The browser will only be expecting one thing, either the JSON or the HTML once all the tiles stuff is done.

I can think of two ways to do this: double request (one for each result type) or use one to generate the other (get the JSON and use JavaScript to construct the HTML on the client).

What are you trying to accomplish that you need both results?

Answer (score 2):

create a new result type for Tiles+JSON & use it... you can't define 2 result types in a result tag.

Answer (score 0):

How about if u have 2 diff results?!

```
<result name="successJSON" type="json"/>

<result name="successTiles" type="tiles">tiles.home</result>
```

then in your server code u just route to the right one?!

Comment: Not a solution, I need to get it simultaneous, if I set type to JSON only, then I can get tiles to work

Comment: the json result type is used almost exclusively for ajax. So one would assume that is what he's after. However tiles renders a page just like a JSP, so one would then need to assume it isn't.